# Java: Beginner using Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am learning Java and am learning I/O w/ `java.util.Scanner`. Specifically I am learning `Scanner` methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int result;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            result += s.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The total is " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've shown us the original problem, can you show what you've already tried?

Comment: Instead of scanning for the next `int` I would scan for the next line and parses the line for an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're checking only

```
while (s.hasNextInt())
```

You could use `try` `catch` to catch the exception ([see documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html)) you get when the program quits, so you can show your error message in the `catch` block without making the program close.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for the while loop (not tested though):

```
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = s.nextLine();
        int parsedInteger;
        try {
            parsedInteger = Integer.parseInt(line);
        } catch(NumberFormatException numEx) {
            if(line.startsWith("q")) break;
            else {
               System.out.println("please enter valid integer or the character 'q'.");
               continue;
            }
        }
        result += parsedInteger;
    }

    s.close();
```

Instead of scanning for `int`'s you can scan for lines and then then parse each line as an int. I feel the advantage of this approach is that *if* any of your `int`'s are malformed you can then handle them appropriately by say displaying an error message to the user.

OR, based on the answer by pinckerman, you can also do this.

```
    while (s.hasNextInt()) {
        try {
            result += s.nextInt();
        } catch(InputMismatchException numEx) {
            break;
        }
    }

    s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try parsing each line:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int sum = 0;
    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a series of integers. Press 'q' to quit.");
    while(true){
        final String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if(line.equals("q"))
            break;
        try{
            final int number = Integer.parseInt(line);
            sum += number;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.err.printf("Invalid: %s | Try again\n", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("The sum is %,d" , sum);
}
```

The idea is to read input line by line and attempt parsing their input as an integer. If an exception is thrown (meaning they entered an invalid integer) it would throw an exception in which you could handle in what ever way you want to. In the sample above, you are simply printing the error message and prompting the user to type in another number.

Answer (score 0):

A smart way you can do it and I've tried before is you use `Integer.parseInt(String toParse);` This returns an int and will reject all non numerical chars.

```
 while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextInt());
    result += i;

    if (result < 2147483648 && result > -2147483648) {
       try{
       throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
       catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```
int result = input.nextInt;
```

this will define your variable for result.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem in your code is "not initializing" result. Once you initialized code will work properly. However, please do not forget you need to tell compiler EOF. Compiler can only understand the stop of the input on the console by EOF. CTRL Z is EOF for windows Eclipse IDE.